# JS AWS SDK - copyObject SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an application using Node and the [AWS-SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) package. I am copying objects from one bucket to another using the [copyObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) method. I'm getting an error that says `SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

I've been able to successfully run the code on my local machine and it copies the files from one bucket to another. The error occurs on our AWS server, which I deployed the application to. The full error is:

```
{ [SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not 
match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.]
message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.',
code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
region: null,
time: Mon Jul 11 2016 12:11:36 GMT-0400 (EDT),
requestId: <requestId>,
extendedRequestId: <extendedRequestId>,
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 66.48076744750142 }
```

Also, I'm able to perform the `listObjects` command. The error is only happening on `copyObject`.
So far, I've tried

- setting `correctClockSkew` to true
- checked the servers time (same as local computer)
- checked the key/secret (loading from a config file and is working locally)
- checked the file names (there are no strange characters. Alphanumeric, '.', '-' and '/')

Here is the code causing the problem:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: <accessKeyId>,
  secretAccessKey: <secretAccessKey>,
  correctClockSkew: true
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
  Bucket: <bucket>,
  Prefix: <prefix>
};

s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (data.Contents.length) {
    async.each(data.Contents, function(file, cb) {
      var file_name = file.Key.substr(file.Key.indexOf('/')+1);
      var copy_params = {
        Bucket: <bucket2>,
        CopySource: <bucket> + '/' + file.Key,
        Key: file_name,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      };

      s3.copyObject(copy_params, function(copyErr, copyData){
        if (copyErr) {
          console.log('Error:', copyErr);
        }
        else {
          cb();
        }
      });
    }, function(err){
        ...
      }
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found a solution to this or not, but this was an issue raised on github and the solution seems to simply URL encode your CopySource parameter with encodeURI():

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1949

Comment: When providing an answer try to add code when possible, and only use external links for sources, explaining anything contained here in your answer directly.